# Return to previous page on button click

Tags: php, html

I've a form which inserts the data into the table and echo "Data submitted". The url remains same when the form is submitted but when i go to previous page by clicking my 'Back' button it hides the echo and remains on same page. Basically i've to hit that 'Back' button twice to go to previous page. Is there anything i could do with this issue?

Or if it's possible to return to previous page on form submission after 5 seconds?

```
<form method='post'>
<input required  type = 'text' name = 'txt_name' value='$username' />
<input required  type = 'text' name = 'txtemail' value='$email' /><br>
<input required  type = 'text' name = 'txt_total' value='$total'/>
<input type='submit' name='btn_save' value='Proceed'/>
<input onclick='window.history.back()' type='button' value='Back' />
</form>
```

Comment: `history.go(-2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function goBack(){
  window.history.go(-2);
}
```

```html
<form method='post'>
<input required  type = 'text' name = 'txt_name' value='$username' />
<input required  type = 'text' name = 'txtemail' value='$email' /><br>
<input required  type = 'text' name = 'txt_total' value='$total'/>
<input type='submit' name='btn_save' value='Proceed'/>
<input onclick='goBack()' type='button' value='Back' />
</form>
```

Hope this helps.